# Linux Server Performance

Tags: networking, server, performance

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 server running some services for me (such as Plex, nginx, Splunk, etc) and intermittently I've noticed that I'll have terrible performance for it. Web responses are slow, SSH is slow, but if I'm local on the machine it seems okay, I think. I'm really not sure what the issue is here, its happening over local and remote connections but when I have tested the network speeds they are 700mbps+. I'm not sure if this is related but when I boot my machine now, it also doesn't start up the network card and I have to tell it to bring it up. Checking the config it looks correct and I haven't found a solution for these. Is there anyway I can test to take a look at what is going on? Syslogs? I'm not even sure where to begin with this.

```
enp5s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::52e5:49ff:feee:41f8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2600:1700:2f70:a300:52e5:49ff:feee:41f8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 50:e5:49:ee:41:f8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 173355052  bytes 151110604042 (151.1 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 189537223  bytes 148316880527 (148.3 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 1  collisions 0
```

Comment: I'm gonna throw this out there since this question doesn't really supply any usable data but is your mtu =1500? There will be knowledgeable people to tell you how to get system data they need. Sry, I just don't use Ubuntu enough to know the commands.

Comment: I did find, installing Nginx on WSL, caused a significant amount of Network Lag, so I abandoned it. I do Emby Media Player.

Comment: It could also be a duplex missmatch. When using the server do you experience slow internet speed? in case the internet is slower than it shoild it could also indicate to be a duplex missmatch https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplex_mismatch. Check internetspeed with `apt install speedtest-cli && speedtest`   also an output of `lshw -c network` might be usefull

Comment: @EODCraftStaff yes my MTU is 1500:

Comment: @AlexOnLinux - I haven't been able to identify its that issue:

Testing download speed................................................................................
Download: 650.18 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed................................................................................................
Upload: 287.41 Mbit/s

Comment: Any ideas of where I can even start to diagnose this issue?